# Joomla adsmanager phone number not correct

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, ads

Created classifieds website with Joomla 2.5 using Adsmanager. The issue is with the phone number. The phone number is not getting updated into the database. I checked the value in the field in the table from PHPMyadmin. I am not sure where the phone number should be inserted into the database. Any help is appreciated.